# gitignore doesn't ignore files in subdirectories

Tags: git, gitignore

I am new to git and try to understand `gitignore`. So far I have a directory I want to exclude called `build`, **except** files with the name `BUILD`.

```
build/**
!build/**/BUILD
```

But it seems the BUILD file is excluded as well. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
resource/obj1/BUILD
resource/obj2/BUILD
resource/obj3/BUILD
```

Comment: From the [gitignore documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) - A slash followed by two consecutive asterisks then a slash matches zero or more directories. For example, "a/**/b" matches "a/b", "a/x/b", "a/x/y/b" and so on.

Comment: So it should work, since I use `!` to exclude the build files?

Comment: Not sure whether I understand what exactly you are trying to achieve. Try `!build/BUILD` or `!build/*BUILD`

Comment: I want to exclude everything in `build` except the files `BUILD`. Both don't work unfortunately :-/

Comment: You can have only one file with a given name in a given directory, so why are saying "files BUILD"? Try clarifying th question and give some more examples as to me it's unclear what your problem is.

Comment: I wrote down more examples. I can't clarify it more :-/

Comment: Sorry, it's still unclear. Can you list all files and provide the actual output together with the expected output.

Comment: It's the typical request. "Exclude everything in a directory except". But I think I found my problem. http://www.randallkent.com/2010/04/30/gitignore-not-working/

Comment: It's great that you've found an answer. You should've told us that you've added everything in the build directory to your repo and you see the files as `not staged` and not as `untracked`. Yes you can't ignore a file that is under git source control, and you first need to remove it and then ignore it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to exclude (whitelist) folders firsts, then `BUILD/` content:

```
build/**
!build/**/
!build/**/BUILD/**
```

See "[`.gitignore` exclude folder but include specific subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/6309)"

- `build/** ignores` files and folders, so `build/aFolder/` is ignored
- `!build/**/BUILD/**` attempts to whilelist a file under `build/aFolder/BUILD/`

But: "**It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.**"

And: `build/aFolder/` is an already ignored folder.

Hence: `!build/**/BUILD/**` does not apply.

**Unless**: you un-ignore *folders* first: `!build/**/` (the trailing `/` is important):
`build/aFolder/` is no longer ignored, even though `build/aFolder/<files>` are still ignored by `build/**`.

*Then*: the `!build/**/BUILD/**` can apply to the folder `BUILD/` *content* (its files), because the *folders* `!build/aFolder/` and `!build/aFolder/BUILD/` are *not* ignored.

---

Check if this is working then with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- build/aFile
git check-ignore -v -- build/path/to/BUILD/aFile
```

The first command should return a `.gitignore` rule line.
The second command should not return anything, since the file should not be ignored.

Comment: I try to understand why I need the second line. Do you have a reference for me? From a logical standpoint only 1 and 3 would be sufficient to me

Comment: @DanielStephens Sure. 1/ ignores files and folders, and once a folder is ignored... any exclusion line (like 3/) within that folder is ignored as well. Hence 2/. See more at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/6309: "**It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.**".

Comment: @DanielStephens I have edited the answer to include those details.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify the files if you want to exclude entire directory.

```
build
```

and git will ignore build directory.

Comment: Hi, I don't want to ignore the entire directory. I want to ignore the directory, **except** the build files